# drawing in a widget contained by another widget

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to understand how kv files work. 
So far, i've been able to tackle a couple errors, but I'm stuck with something that doesn't produces errors but doesn't produce the intended result.

Expected :
My goal is to create a parent widget containing two isntances of a sub-widget. The sub-widget contains a rectangle and a touch-move instruction. I want each instance to cover only part of the main widget (the rectangle is here for me to see where the sub-widget is). I assume the on-touch-move instructions should trigger only on the part of the screen where the sub-widget instance is.

Actual:
The sub-widget rectangles don't show, and the on-touch-move behaviour is triggered anywhere twice (which makes be think both sub-widgets span on the whole screen but the rectangle isn't shown). 
Removing the parent widget canvas doesn't solve my problem, neither does adding only one sub-widget.

What am I doing wrong ?

python file :

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle

class MainWidget(Widget):
    pass

class SubWidget(Widget):
    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        self.center_x, self.center_y = (touch.x, touch.y)
        print touch.x, touch.y

class testApp(App):
    def build(self):
        x = MainWidget()
        return x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testApp().run()
```

kv file:

```
#:kivy 1.8.0

<MainWidget>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 0,1,0
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.center
            size: 10,10
    SubWidget:
        pos: self.width - self.width/5 ,0
        size: self.width/5 , self.height
    SubWidget:
        pos: 0, 0
        size: self.width/5 , self.height

<SubWidget>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1,0,0
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

Thanks in advance for answers.

edit :
1) child widgets should be added within a layout. Still need to find a way to 
position my widgets properly within the layout.
2) widgets' touch events are triggered even if the widget isn't directly clicked. Using widget.collide_point(*touch.pos) makes it work.

edit2 :
Fixed the .kv. Self.parent.pos/size didn't behave consistently so I moved to root.pos/size :

```
#:kivy 1.8.0

<MainWidget>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 0,1,0
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.center
            size: 10,10
    FloatLayout:
        SubWidget:
            pos: root.width - root.width/5 ,0
            size: root.width/5 , root.height
        SubWidget:
            pos: 0, 0
            size: root.width/5 , root.height

<SubWidget>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1,0,0
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I assume the on-touch-move instructions should trigger only on the part of the screen where the sub-widget instance is.

This assumption is incorrect. To check for the collision yourself, you can do `if self.collide_point(*touch.pos): ...` in your `on_touch_move` method.

Also, your positioning problems are caused by using only Widgets - these do not impose anything on their children, so everything except the root widget has the default pos of (0, 0) and size of (100, 100). You should use Layout classes to have widgets automatically resize and position their children.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to put the child elements into a [box layout](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.boxlayout.html#module-kivy.uix.boxlayout).
So it would be something like this.

```
<MainWidget>:
    canvas:
        ...
    BoxLayout:
        SubWidget:
            ...
        SubWidget:
            ...
```

The SubWidget elements' attributes (like pos) might need some changing.

Some more info [here](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#instantiate-children) too.

Comment: I tried using a boxLayout as you suggested. Your code crashes, but commenting out the pos/size on the subWidget instanciation makes it work. The on-touch-move still triggers on the whole screen, though.